# Showing Recent Issues Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: xcode, kotlin-multiplatform

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wv8Gz.jpg)

The "Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code" error commonly arises in Xcode projects, including Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile (KMM) projects. It indicates a problem with a script during the build phase. To resolve, check script configurations, dependencies, and ensure compatibility with Xcode 15.2.

Comment: Was it working before? How did you add the library into your project?

Comment: @Larme no this is the first time i was trying to run kmm project on my device.

Comment: in Xcode open build tab and explore logs, the error should be clarified

Comment: i have fixed this issue by upgrading java version from 16 to 17

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed by upgrading my java version from JAVA 16 to JAVA 17